# is it possible to using prev project archive files in next build project in Kubernetes jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I am build a nodejs project in kubernetes jenkins, after build successful. I am packaged the dist folder(*.js,*.css....) to `tar.gz` and archived, next step to trigger next project.

the Question: is it possible to using the prev project tar.gz, exact the `tar.gz` and then build next project and do other things? any tips will be appreciate? I am searching and check the build dashboard and find no input entry to do this operate.

In traditional jenkins, all project file in the workspace. so I could using cp command or output the compile output as another project input. but in kubernetes the workspace in each pod and could not seem other'd pod output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for the [Copy Artifact Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/copyartifact/). It allows you to copy the archived files from the previous / last successful / last with artifacts job. You can find the documentation [here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/copyartifact/).